# @property or init to set instance variables

Tags: objective-c, xcode

While doing my project I was wondering if I should set my instance variables for a viewcontroller through the viewcontrollers @synthezied properties or creating a new init function that sets the instance variables when the init it called.

For me, it seems like setting the instance variables using the @properties are cleaner.

What do you think?

I dont use nibs or storyboards...

Comment: You can't decide which is the cleaner. Context or representing meaning will decide. Refer answer by @Wade.

Answer (score 2):

Synthesizing the properties just saves you from the trouble of writing setters and getters. Just using `@synthesize` does not initialize your properties. You should definitely initialize them - either in `-init` or when declaring them.

Comment: In the past I used to lazily instantiate them, so that wouldn't be a problem if I did it like that :) I just think the names of the initializers usually get very ugly. They will be like... initwithbla bla1 bla2. If you know what I mean :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for designated initialiser approach as in set instance variables that then can be used via `@synthesized` properties. Initialising view controller and then setting its properties leave the object in an inconsistent state.

Designated initializer:

```
MyViewController * viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithParam1:@"foo" param2:@5];
// now viewController is consistent as presumably it has all properties set
```

Setting properties via setters:

```
MyViewController * viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
// here viewController is inconsistent as it does not have default properties set
[viewController setParam1:@"foo"];
[viewController setParam2:@5];
// only here viewController is consistent and can be used normally
```

Depending on implementation of your initialisers you may set default values for properties without passing them as params to initialiser too, so my second example may be faulty if init silently sets param1 to `@foo` and param2 to `@5`.

Comment: It's just that the designated initialiser never get too pretty to look at. Look at my comment above :) But I get what you mean :)

Comment: You won't be using them too much. And if you use initialisers a lot of times with same params - may be it makes sense to create a static factory method on ViewController's class?

Answer (score 1):

In general your designated initialiser should only have parameters that are strictly necessary.  Anything optional usually goes elsewhere, such as being a readwrite @property.  There's some amount of leeway here, at your discretion - sometimes you'll include an optional parameter because it is actually used the vast majority of the time (and when it's not it has an easy default, like nil or 0).

The idea being that any object returned by an init method should be usable in some fashion.  Requiring additional steps to configure it is almost always indicitive of a poor design.

Following this principle also encourages immutable instances (since in many cases you can specify *all* the necessary parameters upfront), which are advantageous for many reasons - simplicity, predictability, thread-safety, copy-by-retain etc, etc.

For a view controller specifically, typically you would have an initialiser which takes the view to be controlled, and leaves everything else as @properties.  Your view controller should work, in some capacity, with just the view set; all other properties should have reasonable defaults.